# Why is the property opacity available for reading but not font-size?

Tags: javascript

If I want to read the opacity value in to javacript I can just use

```
element.style.opacity
```

but if I want the fontSize I have to use the function below.

```
function findFontSize( element_id )
{
    var element = document.getElementById( element_id );  
    // var theCSSprop = element.style.fontSize; // Does not work  
    // var theCSSprop = element.getPropertyValue("font-size"); // Does not work
    var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle( element, null ).getPropertyValue("font-size");  // This works
    alert( theCSSprop ); 
}
```

Related

http://jsfiddle.net/tUc5v/

Why is this?

Comment: You can't read any element.style properties unless you set them first- in firefox, opera, IE and Safari- I don't know about Chrome, but I'd doubt it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a different syntax for explicitly defined css styles and inherited styles. I'm guessing (though your jsfiddle doesn't match the question) that opacity is being explicitly set, but fontSize is inherited.

UPDATE:
Found this old comment, thought I'd give a little more...

If an element does not have a style explicitly defined in a stylesheet or inline then it falls back to the computed style which is not accessible via the `element.style.property` way.

Another difference is, explicit styles on the style object are camelCase, but computed styles are hyphen-case.

Another thing to note is that properties accessed via the style object are 3x-4x faster than window.getComputedStyle (or document.defaultView.getComputedStyle).

Here's a basic function that can do this for any style (it doesn't check for incorrect input, etc..)

```
/**
 * 
 * @param el Element
 * @param CSS property in hyphen case 
 * @param pseudo pseudo selector (optional, e.g. '::before')
 */
function getStyleValue(el, property, pseudo) {
    // convert hyphen-case to camelCase
    const elStyle = el.style[property.replace(/(\-[a-z])/g, $1 =>  $1.toUpperCase().replace('-',''))];
    return ((elStyle !== '' && !pseudo) 
        ? elStyle
        : window.getComputedStyle(el, pseudo).getPropertyValue(property));
}
```

Comment: this is true, they were set explicitly.

Comment: It's important to note another difference, though the explicit setting was the important one.  You can't ever access `element.style.font-size` because the client parses that as `element.style.font - size`.  However, if `font-size` is explicitly set, you can access that setting using camelCase: `element.style.fontSize`.